# 'clear' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file in npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon

Whenever i tried to clear command line in node it reflects below error

```
'clear' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

while try to access index.js through commond "npm run start" its shows that above mentioned error, can you please anyone help on this?

I am basic learner in NodeJS, tried to run basic javascript file in VS code, but i am not able to clear command line by using command -exec clear

Below is scripts command line in package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "nodemon --exec 'clear && node' ./src/index.js -q"
}
```

Comment: Do you have a `clear` command in whatever OS you're in? Is it really that important to clear the screen anyway?

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR; https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/master/faq.md#how-to-clear-the-console-on-restart

I assume you mean the `clear` command that clears the terminal screen and is called `cls` under windows.
That command is an internal command of the shell you are using (zsh, bash,...).
nodemon runs your command directly and not inside of a shell, but even if it would there is nothing to clear, because it would create a new shell process anyway that is already cleared.

Looking at the nodemon documentation there is an FAQ entry for what you want:

> In your nodemon.json (or in your package.json) you can include the follow event handler to always clear the console when nodemon starts:
>
> ```json
> {
>  "events": {
>    "start": "cls || clear"
>  }
> }
> ```
>
> ~ https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/master/faq.md#how-to-clear-the-console-on-restart

Comment: Thank for your support simon but still i am confused where to place above mentioned comment, please help me to proceed further

Comment: It's described here: https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/master/README.md#config-files

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort to solve my doubt but i am totally ignorant to read documentations. and read it though i am not able to make it. if possible please tell me exactly how can i proceed that?

Comment: create a file named `nodemon.json` and put the json from the docs/answer inside. Also you should get comfortable with documentation, you'll be lost without it ;)

Comment: Thank you so much Simon finally its resolved. I am feeling much happy as well as grateful for you , i hope you will solve my queries in future

Answer (score 0):

Installing the ncurses was enough to solve the issue for me:

```
yum install ncurses
```